# Make ImageView wrap around a certain object

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am essentially trying to replicate this app:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id785725887

I want to be able to upload and image from gallery and then drag it over whatever is in place. Whether it be a tshirt hat or sock. Any ideas on how I would accomplish this with native android?

Comment: I am going to make the assumption that the shirt is actually like a cookie cutter image that overlays your image, where the shirt is what is cut out and the white part is what is remaining of the template. The image you want loaded on the shirt is then loaded in the background and appears through the cut-out shirt portion.

Comment: I think that will be all I need thanks

Comment: No worries, if you want the shading like they have done, you will likely need a second layer for your cookie cutter template that has some alpha value that makes it look somewhat transparent